# Modify a csv file with a Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export-to-csv

I have a .xlsx file converted to .csv.I need to write a script to modify this file(change/rename columns etc.) How can I open this .csv file and save it from within the script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the csv file just like you would open any other file in ruby using the standard File api

```
csv_file = File.open('data.csv', 'r')
```

Parse it manually or use a library like FasterCSV. Make your modifications, writeback to the file and close. There is nothing inherently special about a csv file, work with it like you would with any file in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You should proably work with a CSV library (or in the ruby world a gem). So install the gem,
and your code will look something like this:

```
FasterCSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot make inline modifications to the CSV file. You would have to output via another file.